# flutter google_maps_flutter plugin capability of searching places

Tags: location, maps, flutter

I know this plugin is an unplublished preview on https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter but after playing a little bit with it I haven't found the capability of searching specific locations by name. So I'm wondering if this capability has been added already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it has been added, but an alternative solution could be to hit the Google places API / place search in conjunction with your google_maps_flutter to search for places.